# Plotting the results of a specific cluster

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am new to R, so i do not know if my query is already been repeated before.
I performed k-means clustering with k=3 on a sample data set and the algorithm returns me the desired clustering results. Now I want to plot the results of cluster number 2 to see how far the members in cluster 2 are spaced from one another. How would I do that? Thanks

```
name <- sample(letters[1:25])
age<-sample(20:50, 25, replace=FALSE)
salary <-sample(2000:10000, 25, replace=FALSE)
demo<-data.frame(name, age, salary)
set.seed(299)
study<-kmeans(demo[,-1],centers = 3)
```

Comment: Yes i got K-means clustering with 3 clusters of sizes 12, 6, 7 and also the between SS and within SS values but then how to proceed. I guess thats what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

With `ggplot()`:

```
ggplot(data=demo,
       aes(x=age, y=salary,
           color=factor(study$cluster))) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

To show only the cluster 2:

```
ggplot(data=demo[study$cluster==2,],
       aes(x=age, y=salary)) +
    geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I got an idea now, but since I want only to plot the results of cluster # 2, is there a way to do this. I am thinking of appending the cluster number to each record in "study" data set and then filtering the data set to show records with cluster number = 2 and then doing the plotting i.e. ggplot(study%>%filter(Cluster_number==3),aes(x=age, y=salary,
           color=factor(study$cluster))) +
  geom_point() Is there any way apart from this

Comment: Also if i have another continuous variable in my study data set say "Publications" , and i want this variable also to show in the plot apart from age, salary then how to  do this?

Comment: @TKM see my update. As for your second question I don't really understand it. You might post another question with a reproducible example.

Comment: My suggestion would be to not map color to an external variable like that. Make it tidy, append it to the original dataset. This also serves as a sort of a double check that things are working.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik You mean something like `demo$cluster <- study$cluster`?